# Creating a MVC-restful application upon express

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I'm trying create my own application based on rails (not equal, but similar).

So, i'm creating this basic stuff to send to github, so i can use in any project, and i have a problem with my routes.

I am using the express-resource to create the cruds routes.

This is my app.

Controller/example.js:

```
exports.index = function(req, res, next){
  res.send('forum index');
  next();
};

exports.new = function(req, res, next){
  res.send('new forum');
  next();
};

exports.create = function(req, res, next){
    res.send('create forum');
    next();
};

exports.show = function(req, res, next){
  res.send('show forum');
  next();
};

exports.edit = function(req, res, next){
  res.send('edit forum');
  next();
};

exports.update = function(req, res, next){
  res.send('update forum');
  next();
};

exports.destroy = function(req, res, next){
    res.send('destroy forum');
    next();
};

exports.load = function(id, fn){
  process.nextTick(function(){
    fn(null, { title: 'Ferrets' });
  });
};
```

Them in my routes.js:

```
var express     = require('express');
var resource    = require('express-resource');

var client = express();

routes.resource('example', require('../controllers/example'));


module.exports = routes;
```

and my app.js:

```
// Routes
var routes = require('./routes/routes.js');

app.use('/', routes);
```

Now the problem:

I can access only the index and the new routes. When i try access:

```
http://localhost:3000/example - will show right, but with a 304 http code.

http://localhost:3000/example/new - will show right, but with a 304 http code.

http://localhost:3000/example/create - will show the /show/ and a 304 http code.

http://localhost:3000/example/show - will show the /show/ and a 304 http code.

http://localhost:3000/example/edit - will show the /show/ and a 304 http code.

http://localhost:3000/example/update - will show the /show/ and a 304 http code.

http://localhost:3000/example/destroy - will show the /show/ and a 304 http code.
```

In the terminal, the following error occur:

GET /example/edit 304 1.080 ms - -
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

I'm stuck in this.. i dont know the problem. Please, somebody help! haha

[image]

Thanks Very Much!

Answer (score 0):

```
res.send('forum index');
next();
```

either respond or pass the request along for other middleware to respond, not both.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
function(req, res, next)
```

with

```
function(req, res)
```

And remove **next();**

next don't stop a request.

```
res.send('final output'); // end output
```

Try:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.send('forum index');
};

exports.new = function(req, res){
  res.send('new forum');
};

exports.create = function(req, res){
    res.send('create forum');
};

exports.show = function(req, res){
  res.send('show forum');
};

exports.edit = function(req, res){
  res.send('edit forum');
};

exports.update = function(req, res){
  res.send('update forum');
};

exports.destroy = function(req, res){
    res.send('destroy forum');
};

exports.load = function(id, fn){
  process.nextTick(function(){
    fn(null, { title: 'Ferrets' });
  });
};
```

This is other alternative: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-enrouten

Check this article (spanish) http://blog.mcnallydevelopers.com/cargar-controladores-de-forma-automatica-en-expressjs-con-node-js/

Rails clone? http://sailsjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to call `next()` while you already called `send()` the middleware that called by `next()` trying to call send but couldn't because already sent as the `.send()` doesn't return and your process keep executing, just remove `next()`